# Remove a network from a docker service

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Because our service provider only provides `/24` networks, I had do create multiple networks where containers are attached to.

However I have now the problem, that containers are "dangling" in the status "new" because the network is "full".

Therefore, I want to remove a network from a service and add another one.

I found something like remove a network from a container ([I need to remove a deleted network from a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65038509/i-need-to-remove-a-deleted-network-from-a-docker-container)) but I want to remove the network from a service.

With a further research, I could add a network using `docker service update --network-add name=traefik-net5 containername` - this works fine, but then I also want to remove the other network.

There should also be an option with `--network-rm` like `docker service update --network-rm name=traefik-net4 containername` it is saying `Error: No such network: name=traefik-net4`.

Therefore I could not remove the network traefik-net4 although it is attached to the service.

How can I remove the network treaefik-net4 from the service? Or do I have to delete the service and create a completely new one?

Comment: As a workaround I found a solution, but therefore you need to use portainer (which I am using). From portainer Version 2.0, it is possible to change the network of a service with the UI. You have to go to the service and there you can change it. I still could not fix it using docker commands, but this is feasible solution for me.